# Collapsible Flowbite (Tailwind CSS) navbar works on Vite but not in Vercel?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite, vercel, flowbite

Default Flowbite navbar (https://flowbite.com/docs/components/navbar/#default-navbar) that expands into a dropdown in mobile devices works in React with Vite, but does not work when deployed in Vercel? (The menu button neither expand the menu nor contract.)

These are my config files:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "apis",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "flowbite": "^2.2.1",
    "flowbite-react": "^0.7.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.15",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.4",
    "postcss": "^8.4.32",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.6",
    "vite": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

**tailwind.config.js
**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "node_modules/flowbite-react/lib/esm/**/*.js",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        ivory: "#f3ece4",
        beige: "#e8dccc",
        void: "#373234",
        cherry: "#d84339",
        teal: {
          50: "#f2f9f9",
          100: "#ddeff0",
          200: "#bfe0e2",
          300: "#92cace",
          400: "#5faab1",
          500: "#438e96",
          600: "#3b757f",
          700: "#356169",
          800: "#325158",
          900: "#2d464c",
          950: "#1a2c32",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("flowbite/plugin")],
};
```

**vercel.json**

```
{
    "rewrites":  [
      {"source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/"}
    ]
  }
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
plugins: [react()],
>! })
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into similar problem with the Flowbite navbar-default hamburger menu not working on small screens, but only on the home page; it worked on other pages.

I found a suggestion [here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/discuss/issues/114) that was helpful. Ultimately, what worked for me was to add some inline JavaScript to my html home page template to toggle the "hidden" attribute on the div with my nav elements.

Add this before the button:

```
<script>const toggle = () => menu.classList.toggle("hidden");</script>
```

Add this to the button:

```
<button onclick="toggle()" ...
```

Add this after the div with id='navbar-default':

```
<script>const menu = document.getElementById('navbar-default');</script>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! Would this also be applicable to React JSX components? 

My navbar is a JSX component and does not exist in the HTML document. My understanding is that React components has it's own virtual dom and cannot be accessed by the regular getElementById.

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I'm not using React, and didn't realize that was a constraint.